# Using Latex to draw a Pentagon with a Degree Label

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, polygon

I would like to use Latex to draw a regular pentagon which shows the 72 degree angle between two vertices. It would be nice if it looked something like the image below:

[image]

I currently have the following latex code:

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=blue}]
\def\ngon{5}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\ngon,minimum size=3cm] (p) {};
\foreach\x in {1,...,\ngon}{\node[mystyle] (p\x) at (p.corner \x){};}
\foreach\x in {1,...,\numexpr\ngon-1\relax}{
\foreach\y in {\x,...,\ngon}{
\draw (p\x) -- (p\y);
} }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But I don't know how to reformat it so that instead of the lines connecting each vertex, they all point to a central dot. I'd also like to be able to add the degree. If anyone has any suggestions that would be really helpful!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(p.center)` to draw the lines to the middle. Note that you should `shorten` the radial segments by the line thickness to avoid drawing them beyond the polygon. Here is a macro that allows you to select the number of sides.

`\myshape{4}\quad\myshape{5}\quad\myshape{6}`

[image]

An optional argument allows any Ti*k*Z options to be added, for example, `\myshape[scale=2, transform shape, red, font=\sffamily\tiny]{10}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\newcommand{\myshape}[2][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\scriptsize, #1]
        \pgfmathsetmacro\ang{frac(360/#2)==0?{int(360/#2)}:{360/#2}}
        \node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=#2, minimum size=3cm] (p) {};
        \foreach \n in {1,...,#2} {\draw[shorten >=\pgflinewidth](p.center)--(p.corner \n);}
        \node[draw, circle, minimum size=5mm, label=below:{\ang\textdegree}]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\myshape{4}\quad\myshape{5}\quad\myshape{6}\vspace{2cm}

\myshape[scale=2, transform shape, red, font=\sffamily\tiny]{10}

\end{document}
```

The complicated expression for `\ang` is to avoid angles like `60.0` when the angle is an integer.